# Mysql query with inner join more slow with Order by and Group By

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-order-by, inner-join

on my vps I'm trying to execute a query, I have to extract 20 results in about 1800 records, the query is formed by 3 `INNER JOIN`, if I execute it without inserting the `GROUP BY id ORDER BY id DESC` at the end of the query query is executed in 0.0143 seconds, while if I insert the `GROUP BY id ORDER BY id DESC` at the end of the query, it takes 3.1447 seconds the execution, can you tell me why?

This is the query:

```
SELECT s.nome,s.url as urlSito,s.importospedizione,p.titolo,p.descrizione,p.prezzo,p.img,p.annata,p.formato,p.denominazione,p.regione,c.categoria,c.url,s.id AS sito,p.id AS prodotto,pp.prezzo AS old,pp.data,p.sku 
FROM prodotti AS p 
INNER JOIN siti AS s ON p.sito = s.id 
INNER JOIN categorie AS c ON p.categoria = c.id 
INNER JOIN prodotti_prezzi AS pp ON p.id = pp.prodotto 
WHERE p.attivo = 1 AND s.attivo = 1 AND p.forced = 0  AND 
    ( p.regione = 'Valle d\'Aosta' OR p.regione = 'Piemonte' OR p.regione = 'Liguria' OR 'Lombardia' OR p.regione = 'Trentino-Alto Adige' OR p.regione = 'Veneto' OR p.regione = 'Friuli-Venezia Giulia' OR p.regione = 'Emilia-Romagna' OR p.regione = 'Toscana' OR p.regione = 'Umbria' OR p.regione = 'Lazio' OR p.regione = 'Marche' OR p.regione = 'Abruzzo' OR p.regione = 'Molise' OR p.regione = 'Campania' OR p.regione = 'Puglia' OR p.regione = 'Basilicata' OR p.regione = 'Calabria' OR p.regione = 'Sardegna' OR p.regione = 'Sicilia' )
GROUP BY p.id  
ORDER BY p.prezzo ASC  
LIMIT 0,20
```

[image]

This is the structure:

**Table prodotti:**

```
CREATE TABLE `prodotti` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `sku` text NOT NULL,   `titolo` text NOT NULL,   `descrizione` longtext NOT NULL,   `sito` int(11) NOT NULL,   `prezzo` double NOT NULL,   `qta` int(11) NOT NULL,   `url` text NOT NULL,   `produttore` text NOT NULL,   `regione` text NOT NULL,   `denominazione` text NOT NULL,   `annata` int(11) NOT NULL,   `formato` text NOT NULL,   `attivo` int(11) NOT NULL,   `img` text NOT NULL,   `home` int(11) NOT NULL,   `categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,   `consigli` int(11) NOT NULL,   `forced` int(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `prodotti`
-- ALTER TABLE `prodotti`   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `prodotti`
-- ALTER TABLE `prodotti`   MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**Table siti:**

```
CREATE TABLE `siti` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` text NOT NULL,
  `indirizzo` text NOT NULL,
  `tel` text NOT NULL,
  `pagamento` text NOT NULL,
  `spedizione` text NOT NULL,
  `url` text NOT NULL,
  `email` text NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `emailweb` text NOT NULL,
  `zone` text NOT NULL,
  `data` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aggiornamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `urlaggiornamento` text NOT NULL,
  `img` text NOT NULL,
  `click` double NOT NULL,
  `max` double NOT NULL,
  `ultimo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attivo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `importospedizione` double NOT NULL,
  `descrizione` longtext NOT NULL,
  `web` text NOT NULL,
  `iva` text NOT NULL,
  `sociale` text NOT NULL,
  `avviso` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `siti`
--
ALTER TABLE `siti`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `siti`
--
ALTER TABLE `siti`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**Table prodotti_prezzi:**

```
CREATE TABLE `prodotti_prezzi` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prodotto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prezzo` double NOT NULL,
  `data` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `prodotti_prezzi`
--
ALTER TABLE `prodotti_prezzi`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `prodotti_prezzi`
--
ALTER TABLE `prodotti_prezzi`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**Table categorie:**

```
CREATE TABLE `categorie` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categoria` text NOT NULL,
  `url` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `categorie`
--
ALTER TABLE `categorie`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `categorie`
--
ALTER TABLE `categorie`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I tried to run the same query, on a database clone (same data) on two other servers is the problem does not occur, it only happens when I run it from my vps.

Here is my configuration:

**Database server**

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: MySQL
- Server version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
- Protocol version: 10
- User: root@localhost
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

**Web server**

- Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2g
- Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 -
  $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
- PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation
  mbstringDocumentation
- PHP version: 7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

**phpMyAdmin:** Version information: 4.6.6deb1+deb.cihar.com~xenial.2

Thanks a lot to everyone.

**EDIT**

EXPLAIN result:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

EXPLAIN result on second database:

[image]

Comment: What's the query?  What are your indexes?  What does `explain` tell you?

Comment: Sorry, I skipped over the sentence that mentioned two other servers with cloned database.  But I still think you should not assume that the databases are identical.  Run `explain` to be sure they are using the same plan.

Comment: I'm sorry I updated the post by adding some data on the tables and the query

Comment: Added explain result

Comment: That's a lot of info...  but one question remains:  is the explain the same on all 3 databases?

Comment: Added another explain result (database number 2)

Answer (score 0):

For your query,

```
SELECT s.nome,s.url as urlSito,s.importospedizione,p.titolo,p.descrizione,p.prezzo,p.img,p.annata,p.formato,p.denominazione,p.regione,c.categoria,c.url,s.id AS sito,p.id AS prodotto,pp.prezzo AS old,pp.data,p.sku 
FROM prodotti AS p 
INNER JOIN siti AS s ON p.sito = s.id 
INNER JOIN categorie AS c ON p.categoria = c.id 
INNER JOIN prodotti_prezzi AS pp ON p.id = pp.prodotto 
WHERE p.attivo = 1 AND s.attivo = 1 AND p.forced = 0  AND 
    ( p.regione = 'Valle d\'Aosta' OR p.regione = 'Piemonte' OR p.regione = 'Liguria' OR 'Lombardia' OR p.regione = 'Trentino-Alto Adige' OR p.regione = 'Veneto' OR p.regione = 'Friuli-Venezia Giulia' OR p.regione = 'Emilia-Romagna' OR p.regione = 'Toscana' OR p.regione = 'Umbria' OR p.regione = 'Lazio' OR p.regione = 'Marche' OR p.regione = 'Abruzzo' OR p.regione = 'Molise' OR p.regione = 'Campania' OR p.regione = 'Puglia' OR p.regione = 'Basilicata' OR p.regione = 'Calabria' OR p.regione = 'Sardegna' OR p.regione = 'Sicilia' )
GROUP BY p.id  
ORDER BY p.prezzo ASC  
LIMIT 0,20
```

you need to have indexes on the fields used to join the tables.  You have indexes on the primary keys, but nothing to match them with, so the database has to search through every record of the joined tables.

Add indexes to `prodotti.sito`, `prodotti.categoria`, `prodotti_prezzi.prodotto` and that should make a world of difference. You could also throw in indexes on `attivo`, `forced`, and `regione` for good measure.

My suspicion is that your indexes are not the same on all 3 servers, and the slow one is lacking the indexes.

---

FWIW, a couple of other notes:

1. On prodotti, `unique key id` is superfluous; `primary key` is by definition unique
2. `p.regione = 'Valle d\'Aosta' OR p.regione = 'Piemonte' OR p.regione = 'Liguria' OR 'Lombardia' OR p.regione = 'Trentino-Alto Adige' OR p.regione = 'Veneto' OR p.regione = 'Friuli-Venezia Giulia' OR p.regione = 'Emilia-Romagna' OR p.regione = 'Toscana' OR p.regione = 'Umbria' OR p.regione = 'Lazio' OR p.regione = 'Marche' OR p.regione = 'Abruzzo' OR p.regione = 'Molise' OR p.regione = 'Campania' OR p.regione = 'Puglia' OR p.regione = 'Basilicata' OR p.regione = 'Calabria' OR p.regione = 'Sardegna' OR p.regione = 'Sicilia' )`
   can be more easily expressed as
   `p.regione IN('Valle d\'Aosta','Piemonte','Liguria','Lombardia','Trentino-Alto Adige','Veneto','Friuli-Venezia Giulia','Emilia-Romagna','Toscana','Umbria','Lazio','Marche','Abruzzo','Molise','Campania','Puglia','Basilicata','Calabria','Sardegna','Sicilia')`

Comment: the server is only one, same database. then I tested the same database and the same query on other servers and it works fine.

Comment: The second explain shows a plan that should be faster (eq-ref is waaaay better than all), although there is still room for improvement.  Everything I see points to needing indexes.  The amount of time in "sending data" is misleading; it's actually time crunching the query.  It could be that disk operations are slower on one, and the lack of indexes makes it evident by requiring more searching.  The indexes will help a lot.